# Metal Compute Kernel vs Fragment Shader

Tags: ios, metal

Metal supports `kernel` in addition to the standard `vertex` and `fragment` functions. I found a metal `kernel` example that converts an image to grayscale.

What exactly is the difference between doing this in a `kernel` vs `fragment`? What can a compute `kernel` do (better) that a `fragment` shader can't and vice versa?

Comment: the main difference is that you cannot send vertex positions (or any other mesh/geometry data) to a kernel function as you would to a fragment function. a fragment function returns (usually) a color for each pixel of your output texture while a kernel function which does not have a return (is void) operates on a texture or buffer and can run way more threads simultaneously on grids that can go up to millions of threads. kernels are also used in GPGPU and scientific simulations not only for image processing but a fragment function can only be used in rendering.

Comment: Basically the OpenCL of iOS?

Comment: You can think of it that way, yes. But not only for iOS. Metal also works on tvOS and macOS.

Comment: Of course. I was only referring to iOS since only macOS has an OpenCL framework available for developers.

Comment: And unlike OpenCL, Metal compute is tightly integrated with Metal graphics, so it's easy to use compute as part of a rendering workflow. BTW @Marius, your comment(s) are definitely worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Metal has four different types of command encoders:

- `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`
- `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`
- `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`
- `MTLParallelRenderCommandEncoder`

If you're just doing graphics programming, you're most familiar with the `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`. That is where you would set up your vertex and fragment shaders. This is optimized to deal with a lot of draw calls and object primitives.

The kernel shaders are primarily used for the `MTLComputeCommandEncoder.` I think the reason a kernel shader and a compute encoder were used for the image processing example is because you're not drawing any primitives as you would be with the render command encoder. Even though both methods are utilizing graphics, in this instance it's simply modifying color data on a texture rather than calculating depth of multiple objects on a screen.

The compute command encoder is also more easily set up to do parallel computing using threads:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder

So if your application wanted to utilize multithreading on data modification, it's easier to do that in this command encoder than the render command encoder.